# Urn with replacement

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

An urn contains 2 green balls, 2 red balls, 1 yellow ball, and 1 white ball. You draw 6 balls, with replacement. What is the probability that there is at least one color repeated exactly twice?

Hint - use inclusion-exclusion principle.

My attempt - I generally know how the hint works and I think I get a sense of how to choose/count balls using "with replacement." Having said this, what does the question mean by "repeated exactly twice"? Is it trying to say one color is meant to occur twice, or thrice?

Comment: Hard to say. It's badly phrased; either interpretation seems reasonable.

Comment: exactly twice means exactly twice  in the sense of at least twice, but not at least thrice.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee it's not the "exactly" that's the issue, but the "repeated". If a colour *occurs* twice, how many times is it repeated?

Comment: look,the number of cases with one color having exactly two is $4\cdot 3^4$ how many ways can these be drawn, out of the $4^6$ways to draw balls.